# SSRS - Pass MDX parameter value to SQL query

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, parameters, mdx, business-intelligence

I have a EmployeeID parameter:

```vb
="[Employee].[Employee Id].&[12345678912345]"
```

I have a SQL query that calls for EmployeeID parameter like this:

```vb
Where...AND (EmployeeID = @EmployeeID)
```

I then go into the sql dataset's parameters list and set EmployeeID's value to:

```vb
=LEFT(RIGHT(Parameters!EmoloyeeID.Value,15),14)
```

This should give 12345678912345. EmployeeID column in SQL table has datatype of nvarchar(25).

Now when I use lookup to connect Cube's dataset (dataset of the tablix I am working on) with this SQL dataset,

```vb
=Lookup(Cube's EmployeeName field, SQL's EmployeeName field, SQL's EmployeeStatus, "SQLDataSet")
```

I get no output. I get blank. (I know for fact that there is data because when I execute SQL query in SSMS with EmployeeID declared to 12345678912345, I get right EmployeeeName (matches with Cube's EmployeeName value) and EmployeeStatus values.

What am I doing wrong? Am I doing something wrong to EmployeeID parameter's value manipulation?

Answer (score 1):

Is this a typo?
=LEFT(RIGHT(Parameters!EmoloyeeID.Value,15),14)

Just want to check to ensure it's not a simple fix :-)

Comment: Yep, sorry, it's a type in my post. In the ssrs, its typed correctly. nice catch though. :)